# Localisation issue

Tags: localization, resx, culture

I have set up an MVC4 environment where I have created some localisation using simple resx files in the resources directory. The naming of the file I have used was XXXXX.resx and XXXXX.nl.resx.

This worked brilliantly. I have now changed to a (brilliant) third party application (resxmanager.com) since I expect to use a lot of different languages. This application however, uses the "xx-XX" convention for creating the various language files.

So far, so good. I am able to manage the resource files without any problem. The issue is however, that my application doesn't use the correct resource files. The culture and uiculture indicate that the browser is working in the right (i.e. nl-NL) culture but the proper resources are not selected. I have tried various settings in the web.config ([ui]culture="auto", [ui]culture="xx-XX", [ui]culture="xx" etc) but I'm stuck on what to do next.

Is anyone able to put me into the right direction?

Comment: I went a few steps further. I discovered that (on my system), the Dutch "uiCulture" localisation is returned as "nl" instead of "nl-NL". Using a different browser which is setup as an English version, the returned uiCulture is "en-US".

Comment: Ok - strange thing that I've come across: In Chrome, the uiCulture that is returned is "nl" (Dutch) and "en-US" for English (US). In IE this is "nl-NL" and "en-US". So that's the problem. I have no clue if this problem is a local machine problem, or a Chrome problem :-)